# Ethereum network Sync up with Matic network

Tags: solidity, transactions, synchronization, sidechain, mainnet

We are able to deploy our ERC20 token into Matic Network and it is working fine. But we have few questions here to understand how Matic works with Ethereum Mainnet

Once the contract is deployed in Matic network, how this get sync with Ethereum Mainnet ?

Once we do transactions in Matic Network, what’s the sync time between Matic and Ethereum Mainnet ?

What’s the cost involved for this sync to happen ?

Does user need to bear the cost for the sync ?

Do we have any documentation where all these questions are answered by Matic Team ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think you need to read everything from getting started to advance. some of the questions are answered here https://docs.matic.network/docs/develop/getting-started

Comment: I gave an initial read to that document.. still not clear. Any other tutorial / pointer for this ?

Comment: u really need more than initial read to that, took me a complete day to try to read it, I haven’t seen others good resources yet, sorry. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Once the contract is deployed in Matic network, how this get sync with Ethereum Mainnet ?

It doesn't.

You need to use a [bridge](https://docs.matic.network/docs/develop/ethereum-matic/getting-started/) to move tokens between two different chains, like Polygon (Matic) and Ethereum mainnets. The security guarantees are lower and transaction times are higher for the bridged transactions.

A separate token contract needs to be deployed on the both ends of the bridge.

Answer (score 0):

> Once we do transactions in Matic Network, what’s the sync time between Matic and Ethereum Mainnet ?

Absolutely! they are implementing the Polygon infrastructure on the foundation of Plasma. For this, Plasma framework mandates proofs of the transactions/blocks produced on the side chains to be published on the mainchain. The public checkpointing layer will validate all the transactions happening on the side chains and publish the proofs to the mainchain. To ensure foolproof security of side chain transactions, the mainchain Plasma contract contains various kinds of Fraud Proofs where any sidechain transactions can be challenged for any fraudulent activity. If a challenger succeeds, the stakes of the side chain actors involved in the fraud are slashed and are transferred to the challenger.

FYI: This is well written in their documentation FAQ section.

> What’s the cost involved for this sync to happen ?

But on this I have not precise answer. Can any one help on this?